# PendingIntent from AlarmManager not activating

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-context, android-pendingintent

I have a test application that, on a button press, is supposed to use `AlarmManager` to call a service one minute after the button press. Below is the code for the MainActivity class

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private View mContentView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        hideBar();
    }

    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean b){
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(b);
        hideBar();
    }

    private void hideBar(){
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    protected void press(View view){


        Intent alI = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ARec.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 126, alI, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000*60, pi);
        Log.d("Main","Alarm set");

    }

    public static class ARec extends BroadcastReceiver{
        public ARec(){
            super();
            Log.d("Rec","Constructed");
        }
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i){
            Toast.makeText(c,"Receiver",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.d("Rec","Received");
        }
    }

}
```

The layout for this activity is in the below XML file. It is simply a button that, upon being pressed, called `press()`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".MainScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button"
            android:onClick="press"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Finally, we have the manifest file. As you can see, I registered ARec as a receiver, so I imagine that should not be an issue. I also included just about any of the permissions I'd imagine this test application would require.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.funguscow.testapp">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:maxSdkVersion="27" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:enabled="true" android:name=".MainScreen$ARec" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm running this from Android Studio, on a Pixel API 27 emulator running Android 8.1. Given the code I have in the MainScreen class, I would expect that after I press the button, I would see "Alarm set" in the log, then after 60 seconds, I would see "Received" in the log, as well as a toast on the emulator. While I see the "Alarm set" message upon the button press, I never see anything indicating that the intent is received. No "Received" message and no toast. I have tried replacing `set` with `setExact`, to no difference. I set the Alarm type to RTC_WAKEUP, but the screen is on when it should activate, so that shouldn't make a difference, I think. Why is it that the intent I set to the AlarmManager to occur after 60 seconds (I have tried other time intervals as well), never happens?

Comment: `PendingIntent.getService()` is for starting a `Service`. You want `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. Also, you forgot to call `show()` on your `Toast`.

Comment: I made those changes, and now the Toast does appear, however after the first alarm, if I try to press the button again, the Log messages stop appearing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Does the `Button` stop responding? Does its log show? Does the alarm stop working? The `Toast`? Its log? You're setting the same alarm each time, so if you set it again before it fires, it just pushes the current one ahead.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. What I mean is that the first time I set the alarm, it functions as expected. After that first alarm is completed, if I set the alarm again, it functions on the emulator as expected(i.e. it shows the Toast), but the Log doesn't display the "Alarm Set" or "Received" messages.

Comment: Dunno. That's likely some issue or hiccup in your IDE, since the alarm is still working. I can't really think of any specific configuration or setting that would cause that odd behavior, though. Are you sure you're not just missing them? Are you filtering on just your logs, or process?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are running the Receiver in a separate process, for some reason, so that might have something to do with it. Do you really need to do that?

Comment: I suppose not, but I'm not sure what in my code causes it to be a separate process, or how I would get it to run in the same process.

Comment: It's the `android:process` attribute on the `<receiver>` element in the manifest. You can just remove that. You might need to completely rebuild afterwards.